# How to go back to certain page with angular router (angular 6)?

Tags: angular, angular6

In my application I have what you would call a homepage and a finish page. In between those pages there could be anywhere from 2 - 4 screen depending on user interaction. Once the user reaches the final page and completes it I'm wanting the application to always go back to the homepage.

On other instances of this in my application I'm using window.history.go(-1) to go back a page, but since this flow can be variable I'm looking for the best way to go back to the homepage not knowing whether it is back 2 or 4 pages in the history.

Whats the best way to approach a situation like this using angular 6?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `navigateByUrl` method of the Router in your compoent like this:

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {}

navigateToHomepage() {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/homepage');
}
```

---

Regarding going back one or several pages what you could do is to add BACK button somewhere on your page, that will programmatically sent user back one page at a time from the location history. Angular has `Location` service for these types of situations:

```
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

constructor(private location: Location) {}

goBack() {
  this.location.back();
}
```

Location service docs: https://angular.io/api/common/Location

Comment: If I use that on the final page that will send me back to the homepage correctly. But then if I use the browser button to go back won't it send me right back to the complete page?

Comment: that looks like it will allow me to go back. but is there a way to look at whats in the history and analyze it? then determine how many routes to go back off of that?  If that is not possible I can probably do some keeping track of that outside of the routing but thought there may be an easy way to look at history/routes and make decisions based on that.

Comment: You can't access the contents of the History object. From MDN web docs for ```Window.history```:
`For security reasons the History object doesn't allow the non-privileged code to access the URLs of other pages in the session history, but it does allow it to navigate the session history.`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history

Answer (score 0):

Use an [AuthGuard](https://angular.io/guide/router)  on all routes that aren't the homepage, and store a value in a service. When you complete the final page, you set the value in the service as having been completed the final stage. Get the AuthGuard to check that value in the service and if it's been marked as completed then you return false on the CanActivate function.